# How do I format start and end dates into custom format in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, momentjs

I have an event that has a start date and an end date as follows:

```
var startDate = '10/9/2014 10:00:00 AM'
var endDate = '10/10/2014 5:00:00 PM'
```

So my event starts Thursday and ends on Friday

I would like to display it in the following format

**Thursday & Friday Oct 9-10**

and if its a single day

**Thursday Oct 9th**

and longer than 2 days

**Thursday - Sunday Oct 9 - 12**

I think momentjs might be the way to go about doing this but I have not used it yet and thought I would post the question while I try to work it out on my own and see what you guys suggest.

Comment: moment will be helpful, but your approach to asking is wrong...try first, then when you have problems ask questions

Comment: The problem with trying everything before asking is two fold, there are too many things to try. Asking people to share there approaches to problems is reasonable. I am not asking someone to write the code but share what they do if they have done something like this. I have been working this problem and was stuck so I posted. Second, people like to get points and if the question isn't one that is asked it's a great idea to get a good discussion going. Have you used sugar.js or date.js?

Comment: steps are fairly straightforward. Use date difference to determine if same day, one day apart or more than one day apart. Adjust output for one of the three conditions. A library isn't needed but since they have some convenience methods can be helpful. You will have to create the output format for 2 of the cases. As for `get discussion going` , that's not how SO works

Comment: Lots of opinions about how things "should" work, but thanks for the input. If you want to put that as an answer I will give it to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's no JavaScript Date constructor that allows you to pass in culture information so that it uses localized date formats. Your best bet is to use the constructor that takes the year, month, and day separately:

```
var parts = dateString.split('/');
var date = new Date(parseInt(parts[2], 10), 
                parseInt(parts[1], 10), 
                parseInt(parts[0], 10));
```